# SQLPackage DriftReports with readonly access only

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

Can I generate DriftReports on my databases using SQLPackage when all I have is readonly access to the target?

I guess not.. but what permissions do I need and where?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it if you have VIEW DEFINITION permissions on the database(s).

Comment: But isn't a snapshot of the schema saved somewhere on the target database?

Comment: No. Any snapshots related to SSDT are manually initiated. If you want to compare the schema in the DB against your project, you need "View Definition" permissions on the database.